# app crash when ListView is empty | ListView dont show content if i use ArrayList<>()

Tags: java, android, listview

My **ListView** crush when its empty. I want to show on it *EmptyView*. I've found few 'solutions' but they didnt helped me.. I've tried **' List valueList = new ArrayList<>(); '** and with that ***setEmptyView*** working, but when **ListView** shouldn't be empty I only saw ***setEmptyView***... 
Please help me to fix it, here is my code:

**Adapter:**

```
List<User> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here I've got error without ArrayList:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this.valueList.size();
}
```

**Activity:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);
        if(adapter!=null && !adapter.isEmpty()) {

            ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {

            MessagesListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.tv_no_result));
        }
     }
```

**ERROR** (without ArrayList)

```
java.lang.nullpointerexception: attemp to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: have you initialised  studentList =new ArrayList(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this.valueList != null ?  this.valueList.size() : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now :)

Comment: nice to help you